# return value of last dates and names across multi-columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this 1000x6 dataframe. How do I add another two columns: column[latest person], column[latest date] to display the last name and
 Action Date / Time of it ?

input:

```
    Reviewer 3   Action Date / Time.2       Approver 1   Action Date / Time.3        Approver 2   Action Date / Time.4


3970          0                      0      Pat McEntee  10.04.2018 - 11:01:55                 0                      0
3971  John Hunt  12.04.2018 - 17:07:54  Paul Monnington  24.04.2018 - 16:22:17                 0                      0
3974          0                      0       Mike Smith  16.04.2018 - 09:30:06                 0                      0
3975          0                      0   Peter McNamara  13.04.2018 - 16:15:27  Stephen Harrison  20.04.2018 - 11:32:39
3977          0                      0   Ananth Sarathy  17.04.2018 - 17:37:03                 0                      0
3978  John Hunt  19.04.2018 - 09:08:12    Sandra Osteni  19.04.2018 - 09:12:38   Amanda Bardwell  01.05.2018 - 09:01:20
3979  John Hunt  19.04.2018 - 09:08:12    Sandra Osteni  19.04.2018 - 09:09:36   Amanda Bardwell  01.05.2018 - 09:02:08
3980  John Hunt  19.04.2018 - 09:08:12    Sandra Osteni  19.04.2018 - 09:13:01   Amanda Bardwell  01.05.2018 - 09:00:49
3981  John Hunt  17.04.2018 - 15:52:58    Sandra Osteni  19.04.2018 - 09:11:58   Amanda Bardwell  01.05.2018 - 09:00:17
3982  John Hunt  17.04.2018 - 15:52:01    Sandra Osteni  19.04.2018 - 09:11:22   Amanda Bardwell  01.05.2018 - 09:01:34
3984          0                      0       Mike Smith  04.05.2018 - 14:51:58                 0                      0
...
4012          0                      0      Trent Mason  23.04.2018 - 12:56:04        Mike Smith  23.04.2018 - 15:03:06
4013          0                      0      Trent Mason  23.04.2018 - 12:57:26        Mike Smith  23.04.2018 - 15:14:41
4014          0                      0      Trent Mason  23.04.2018 - 12:56:58        Mike Smith  23.04.2018 - 15:15:46
4015          0                      0      Trent Mason  23.04.2018 - 12:56:45        Mike Smith  23.04.2018 - 15:05:52
4016          0                      0      Trent Mason  23.04.2018 - 12:57:40        Mike Smith  23.04.2018 - 15:03:39
4017          0                      0      Trent Mason  23.04.2018 - 12:55:14        Mike Smith  23.04.2018 - 15:04:52
4018  John Hunt  23.04.2018 - 10:29:59    Sandra Osteni  30.04.2018 - 13:09:01     Sandra Osteni  30.04.2018 - 13:09:19
4019          0                      0      Trent Mason  23.04.2018 - 12:55:50        Mike Smith  23.04.2018 - 15:09:18
```

Desired output:

```
 Latest person  Latest date

  Pat McEntee      10.04.2018 - 11:01:55
  Paul Monnington  24.04.2018 - 16:22:17 
  Mike Smith       16.04.2018 - 09:30:06
  Stephen Harrison 20.04.2018 - 11:32:39
  Ananth Sarathy   17.04.2018 - 17:37:03
...
  Sandra Osteni    30.04.2018 - 13:09:19
  Mike Smith       23.04.2018 - 15:09:18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to get right-most column pairs as `Latest person/date`. In order to achieve this quickly, after replacing `0` with `NaN`, do column-wise forward filling and take the right-most information for the new columns.

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace("0", np.nan)

persons = df[df.columns[::2]].fillna(axis=1, method='ffill')
dates = df[df.columns[1::2]].fillna(axis=1, method='ffill')

df['Latest person'] = persons[persons.columns[-1]]
df['Latest date'] = dates[dates.columns[-1]]
```

Comment: ffill is such a great idea! I was trying to get the boolean of cells contains dates but yours is way more sophisticated.:) thanks heaps!

Comment: @Candice, yw, I simplified the code since I noticed that my initial expression was a little bit redundant.